# Securing mod wires to PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I have done a few mods to a PCB with 36 gauge mod wire. Obviously this wire is so thin that it only takes a few bends back and forth to break it. What is the best way to secure this in place on the PCB? I have tried super glue but that makes a mess because it flows too easily.

Comment: There's gel type superglue that's far easier to use than the normal low viscosity fluid, but even that is likely to slump before setting unless you spray it with an activator to set it quickly. There are two part epoxies that I've used to good effect in similar circumstances, the quick set (5 minute) stuff will begin thickening within a minute or so, so you can time when to drop the mix into place if you want to build up a supporting collar around the joint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At work I use Dow Corning 3145 RTV silicone adhesive for this very purpose. We also use it to secure flex cables in their connectors, secure right-angle parts such as capacitors to the board surface, fill small gaps to make the product waterproof, electrical component insulation, and so on. It is chemical-resistant, water-resistant, corrosion-resistant, non-conductive, and sticks to just about anything. There are many different uses for it, and in my opinion it is absolutely indispensable.

[image]

And to prevent this from being a specific product plug (I am not affiliated with the company in any way, I just like the product), I will say that just about any silicone adhesive ***designed for printed circuit board use*** will probably work great in this sort of application.

Comment: Beware this is extremely different than hardware store RTV silicone!   The hardware store product is hazardous to electronics as unlike this it releases acetic acid while it cures.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you very much for emphasizing this. I have changed the text in my answer to bold italics clarifying that it must be PCB-grade RTV.

Comment: What's the shelf life of that kind of RTV? It's always like $60+ for a few dozen mL and I'm hesitant to spend money on it since whenever I need some it's never very much.

Comment: From the technical data sheet: `When stored at or below 30°C in the original unopened containers, this product has a usable life of 12 months from the date of production.`

Comment: @DerStrom8 This was my final solution. It worked very well. Thank you.

Comment: @user8908459 I am very happy to hear it helped!

Answer (score 4):

Kapton tape.

Enamel paint. (Nail polish might even work in a pinch.)

Hot glue for larger wires.

Answer (score 3):

Use a **needle** which you dip into the super glue to make tiny glue dot and (right angled) tweezers to keep the modification wire in place.
Or use hot melt; same procedure.
Hot melt has the benefit you can melt it again and you can kind of control the cool down using your hot air station.

Answer (score 2):

Our PCB EMS facility used wire similar to WW AWG30 or smaller , soldered and Loctite bonded with 1 part instant adhesive for strain relief from vibration. 1 glue dot per 5 cm.

I prefer annealed magnet wire. AWG30 or smaller.

I was Eng Mgr for C-MAC WINNIPEG and global Design Services Mgr with over 100 factories now all sold twice and owned by the largest EMS provider overseas.

Comment: Do you have more specifics on the Loctite product?

Comment: 20yrs ago , no I forget the model number 647?  but pretty common low viscosity, and used under clean air  flow control for OSHA.

Comment: But for large mass strain relief, most use some PU white dispensers, I just use PLC4000 but to high volatile former versions were stronger for heavy parts and fast drying.

Comment: Isn't Loctite instant adhesive pretty much just super glue?

Comment: Yes except they have more than a dozen flavours , 1 or 2 part, more and less carcinogenic and always kept in the freezer. Some for medical surgery.

Answer (score 2):

Try Circuit Medic Wire Dots. These wire Dots; a wire tacking system is  a substitute for the traditional glue or Loctite adhesive.
Wire dots is specifically designed for long term bonding to printed circuit boards and high surface energy plastics for the aerospace, medical and industrial equipment, automotive, appliance and electronic markets. Check them out at this link.

**_______________________________**

[Circuit Medic Wire Dots](https://www.circuitmedic.com/products/wire-dots.html#:%7E:text=when%20bonding%20wires.-,Wire%20Dots%20make%20the%20job%20of%20bonding%20jumper%20wires%20neat,highly%20conformable%2C%20high%20strength%20bond.)

"Wire Dots are a wire tacking system consisting of pre-cut shapes of a thin, flexible polymer film coated on one side with a high performance, electronics grade permanent pressure sensitive adhesive. The result is a highly conformable, high strength bond.

Wire Dots will hold secure after exposure to numerous chemicals including cleaning solutions/sprays, saponifiers, mild acids and alkalies. And will hold secure through a typical circuit board hot water wash."

[image]

Comment: Given your username it would be a good idea to state your relationship with Circuit Medic as the post looks rather like a promotional post and may be deleted as "spam".

Comment: It is acceptable to propose your own products in an answer AS LONG AS the answer is relevant (which this is) and AS LONG AS you state that you are the seller of the product or associated in some way. Please indicate your relationship if any to Circuit Medic. If NOT associated with them please say so.

Comment: NOTE TO SE EE USERS: The product is directly relevant to the question and looks like a useful solution - albeit somewhat more expensive than some alternatives.